# EF5 and .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm thinking about this scenario.

In desktop application I will create EF STE enity. App will be using EF 5 and .NET 4.0.
This entity will be send through WCF to server where will be .NET 4.5 and also EF5.

Is this supported scenario? (i'm failing to find anything useful) I would like to have performance benefits in .net 4.5 on server side.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the application also running a database? Also, I would recommend creating message entities so you can reduce the amount of data you need to send across the wire to/from your services.

Comment: Desktop app is reading data from MS SQL(using EF). Then, after some modification, is enitity sended to server. Server will do some more operation with entity and then entity will be saved.

Comment: Where do you plan on seeing a performance increase? If you create the entity on the server directly it will be much quicker than creating it on the desktop and sending it over WCF.

Answer (score 1):

If the desktop application is also doing things to a database I'm going to assume it's a different one than is on the server. You'll still want to convert complex entities into simpler ones. For instance if you have an entity that contains a list of other entities that you know already exist on the server, translate that into a message entity (by convention just append Message to the entity name i.e. `EntityName` -> `EntityNameMessage`) before sending it over the wire by selecting the Ids from the original entity when you translate, rather than the list's entire contents. This would be one way to gain performance.

Alternatively you're using the same database on the client and the server, which is probably a bad practice since you would have to recycle EF on the server every time the client updated an entity in its database, since EF wouldn't know about the change.

Comment: Thanks.
Database is the same. Also DataContext is the same. (dll is shared)